# What are the original names of the months in Japanese?

Tags: history

Currently, ichigatsu, nigatsu, sangatsu.....however the original names of the months were different than what is spoken today. I want to learn the original names of the months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar:

> 1. 睦月　「むつき」
> 2. 如月　「きさらぎ」
> 3. 弥生　「やよい」
> 4. 卯月　「うづき」
> 5. 皐月　「さつき」
> 6. 水無月　「みなづき」
> 7. 文月　「ふみづき」 (or「ふづき」)
> 8. 葉月　「はづき」
> 9. 長月　「ながつき」
> 10. 神無月　「かんなづき」 (or「かみなづき」)
> 11. 霜月　「しもつき」
> 12. 師走　「しわす」 or 「しはす」

There are a couple variants to some of them that you can see on the Wikipedia link.  Also note that

> The old Japanese calendar was an adjusted lunar calendar based on the Chinese calendar, and the year—and with it the months—started anywhere from about 3 to 7 weeks later than the modern year, so in historical contexts it is not entirely accurate to equate the first month with January.

So you can't really just use these names willy-nilly to replace the current month convention.